# Jqplot Date renderer padding issue

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am facing a problem regarding [jqplot](http://jsfiddle.net/33jEG/) with Date being the X axis.

My code is

```
var data = [
    ["10/23/2011", 266522], 
    ["10/24/2011", 170287], 
    ["10/25/2011", 2175], 
    ["10/26/2011", 1794]
];

$.jqplot('chart1', [data], {

    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        }
    }
});​
```

My date range starts from 23rd October 2011.

**However, the graph that is rendered always starts from 22nd October 2011.**

I know the alternatives are to use min and max.

But I also want the tick interval to be evenly spaced. The following is what I try to to achieve by evenly spacing out the date labels in the graph.

```
var chart = $('chart1');
chart.resetAxesScale();
var tickInterval = Math.ceil(chart._plotData[0].length / chart.axes.xaxis._numberTicks);
    var newTickInterval = tickInterval * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    chart.axes.xaxis.tickInterval = newTickInterval;
chart.replot();
```

This will basically even out the tickIntervals and the x axis won't be messy.

I have even tried setting the chart with min and max values, and using the above code to evenly space out dates, but I have no luck. The min and max values are resetted on "`chart.resetAxesScale()`". Even if I put an option of using the existing min,max in the resetAxesScale method, the graph doesn't honor these values.
The 'pad' attribute in the axis options doesn't work with DateTimeAxisRenderer.

There is one tick from the start date always.
Would be really helpful if someone can point out my mistake.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to play with "`pad`", "`padMin`" and "`PadMax`" options, but it seems that the "`$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer`" plugin don't permit to use these option.

Here is a fiddle using `pad` but without "`$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer`" : http://jsfiddle.net/33jEG/4/

The best way is to use `min / max` options, sorry

Comment: The min definitely works in the case using `$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer`. In my instance I have multiple series and this is what I added to get rid of the space on the left side `min: dataObj.array[0][0][0]`. In the OP's case it will be `min: data[0][0]` in the `xaxis`

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar problem for padding on date axis, so in the end used min max to set the range and adjust the range using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library to parse the date. Hope it helps.

```
var padding = 0.05;
var min = moment(data[0][0]);
var max = moment(data[data.length - 1][0]);
var pad = (max.valueOf() - min.valueOf()) * padding;
min = moment.unix((min.valueOf() - pad)/1000);
max = moment.unix((max.valueOf() + pad)/1000);

<...>

axes: {
  xaxis: {
    min: min.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
    max: max.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
    rendererOptions: {
       tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
    },
   }
}
```